# The vector logo disappear after printing

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, logo

I got a problem with the vector logo.
I had created the artwork with photo, vector logo and text.

Unfortunately, when my client printed the artwork, the logo has disappeared!
I have checked everything, my artwork is perfectly complete, all in one layer.

I got this logo from my client and they said that they copy the logo from PDF file. I'm not sure, can the problem happen from this reason?

thank you.

Comment: Wow, that's amazing, the logo doesn't even show in your question, it must have disappeared from here too :)) (sorry, I had to do that). But really now, it would be help if you added an image of your work. Best of luck!

Comment: The document color mode is set to CMYK ?

Comment: Um, don't forget that vectors have to have a stroke width and colour to be visible. Also, the stroke width has to be wide enough to be visible—hairline is the minimum. Best practices recommends 1/4 pt. as the minimum line width. Lastly, don't forget vectors enclose areas that must be filled. I know you must know this; but, you might check your various parameters to see if they had changed.

Answer (score 1):

Open your artwork in Illustrator, select the elements that are 'disappearing' and, in the **Attributes** panel, make sure `Overprint Fill` and/or `Overprint Stroke` aren't checked.

You can also quickly check if you're going to have any overprint issues by going `View > Overprint Preview`.

Answer (score -3):

I've encountered the same problem before. A white filled logo disappered and the file format I used for printing was PDF. First, try check the color fill for that vector and see if it's a plain color (usually happen to white color) and it's ticked as overprint, untick the overprint fill. Then try resave and print the file again. Second method, copy the design to a new artboard and save again as new file. Possibly the working file had corrupted. I always try to avoid using PDF format for printing, because sometimes it can go wrong. My other method is save my ai working file to EPS and then open it in Photoshop at 72 to 100 resolution (good enough for printing) and save the design in Jpg format. Everything will be flatten. Hope this help :)

Comment: A 72PPI JPG is **not** "good enough for printing"!

Comment: Not PPI, Resolution in Photoshop. and sorry, not DPI either. I used the wrong term just now. Try drag an EPS file to Photoshop, that's when you can set the resolution. If you set it 300 resolution and if ur computer isn't that good, you can go sleep for few hours waiting for ur Photoshop to load it out for you.

Comment: No I know, that is PPI... still 72 isn't good enough for print.

Comment: depends on ur work size especially for large format printing, . if it's heavy enough, don't think you want to try 150 and above. That's why I said between 72 to 100 because :)

Comment: Large-format yes, but no one said anything about large format. 300ppi is a general rule of thumb for print, but high end stuff can easily be 600... 72–100ppi is not good enough for general print work. Most computer screens are more than that and its generally excepted that print work needs to be significantly higher resolution than digital work.

Comment: I'm with @Cai on this one--300dpi is a hard and fast rule for printing, only to be ignored in exceptional cases. -1.

Comment: there's a different between ppi, dpi and resolution. I hope you can go look up for it and don't get confused with the method i just shared. I worked in a printing company, I run the machines, both digital and large format, even preparing file for offset, so these are some of my methods to share. but somehow, designers are all initiative, I'm sure you have ur own way to solve problems. peace ✌ hehe